# Swift & Firebase - Cloud firestore scalable?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm really new on Cloud Firestore, so it's a bit strange for me to structure the database.

I would like to save my workouts. If I were on RealtimeDatabase I would do something like that:

> ```
> WorkoutResults
>  |
>  +--AutoID
>  |   |
>  |   +--date
>  |   +--userID
>  |   +--result
> ```

AND

> ```
> UserWorkoutResult
>  |
>  +--UserID
>  |   |
>  |   +--WodResultGeneratedID
>  |
> ```

In that way, I can only fetch one node to a specific user.
But if I understand well on Cloud Firestore, it's not possible to query on subcollections.

So my question is, do you think this structure is good enough to scale?

> ```
> WorkoutResults
>  |
>  +--AutoID
>  |   |
>  |   +--date
>  |   +--userID
>  |   +--result
> ```

By doing something like:

```
.whereField("userID", isEqualTo: "userIDString").whereField("date", isEqualTo: theDateIWant) ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query looks fine to me. And as Firestore promises, its performance is only related to the number of matching `WorkoutResults`, not to the size of that collection.

But you could get the exact same result by querying `collection("Users").doc("userIDString").collection("WorkoutResults").whereField("date", isEqualTo: theDateIWant)` in your first data structure. The only thing that isn't possible there is to query across the `WorkoutResults` for multiple users, since querying across multiple collections isn't possible.

Comment: The problem is that I can't query collection("userIDString") because it's not a collection but a document.. I can't add a collection first right?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear there.  You start with a collection name, then a doc, then a collection, then a doc, etc. I updated my answer to show one possible structure. Note that the collection names are usually fixed strings, while the document names are often variables from the app.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, really helpful!